# parsing regex - (Not enough )'s

Tags: c#, regex

I made a tiny database with books and trying to get titles, authors and year of book with regex in c# but error occured.

Database looks like this:

```
Eragon // Christopher Paolini // 2005

The Fellowship of the Ring // J. R. R. Tolkien // 1954
```

And code:

```
Regex r = new Regex(@"(?<title>(.*)//" +
                    @"(?<author>(.*)//" +
                    @"(?<year>(.*)$");
```

Error:

```
parsing "(?<tytul>(.*)//(?<autor>(.*)//(?<rok>(.*)$" - Not enough )'s.
```

Comment: That's a pretty clear error message - you have unmatched parens. You open six groups, and only close 3.

Comment: Go to this site (http://www.regexr.com/) and test out your regex...

Answer (score 9):

You forget to close all the named capturing groups.

```
@"(?<tytul>(.*))//(?<autor>(.*))//(?<rok>(.*))$"
               ^               ^             ^
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/cR7xK2/1)

By turning the greedy quantifiers `.*` at the first to non-greedy `.*?` would avoid [backtracking](http://www.regular-expressions.info/recursebacktrack.html).

```
@"^(?<tytul>(.*?))//(?<autor>(.*?))//(?<rok>(.*))$"
```